# SQL: counting matches within a string of dates

Tags: sql, impala

I have a string column called `'days'` that is of arbitrary length.  There can be gaps in the dates.  Here is an example:

`2016-01-21,2016-01-22,2016-01-26,2016-01-27,2016-01-28,2016-01-30`

I have another column called `'start_date'`.  I want to calculate the number of matches in 'days' for a date range starting with the `'start_date'` and ending d days later.

For example, if the `'start_date'` is `2016-01-27` and the range is 10 days, the output should be 3.  Note, that each row can have a different value for `'start_date'`.

Comment: are dates always previously ordered?

Comment: dates are always ordered.  I'm using Impala

Answer (score 0):

add  10 days to start_date using adddate and subtract current date using date_sub, then do group by to get count.check out this link for date functions
http://www.cloudera.com/documentation/archive/impala/2-x/2-0-x/topics/impala_datetime_functions.html

Comment: The problem is that 'days' is a comma separated string of dates, so I don't see how I can directly apply a date function.   I've been trying with string functions such as: WHERE days LIKE "%2016-01-27%", but I can only get it to work for one date instead of a range of dates.

Comment: I think you need to create some temp table  and store splitted  dates. select str_date into v_str_date from ....try to break the string based on comma and take that substring as follows while (instr(v_str_date,',')>0) loop  begin v_date := substr(v_str_date,instr(v_str_date,','))  and insert it into temp table. end.  Now , query the table by providing range.